# Split a string into two

Tags: ruby

How can I split strings as follows?

```
"1 Bedroom / 1 1/2 Bath"
# ... => ["1 Bedroom ", "1 1/2 Bath"]

"1 Bedroom / 1/2 Bath"
# ... => ["1 Bedroom ", "1/2 Bath"]
```

I tried:

```
"1 Bedroom / 1 1/2 Bath".split('/')
# => ["1 Bedroom ", " 1 1", "2 Bath"]
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-split)? The answer is there.

Comment: "1 Bedroom / 1 1/2 Bath".split(' / ') => adding a space before and after backslash will do right ?

Comment: Your question leaves a lot of room for interpretation. What are the **rules** for splitting the strings? Simply a slash surrounded by whitespace?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
"1 Bedroom / 1 1/2 Bath".split(' / ')
```

Comment: That is not what OP asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Try with adding spaces:

```
str = "1 Bedroom / 1 1/2 Bath"
str.split(' / ')
```

Comment: That is not what OP asked for.

Answer (score 2):

If you specify 2 as a second paramether to the split method, then it would do the way you intended.

```
a="1 Bedroom / 1 1/2 Bath"
p a.split('/',2)
```

Result

```
["1 Bedroom ", " 1 1/2 Bath"]
```

and this one would strip the trailing and leading space for each string in the array

```
p a.split("/",2).map(&:strip)
```

Result

```
["1 Bedroom", "1 1/2 Bath"]
```

Comment: That is not what the OP is asking for. If you change your first argument to `'/ '` instead of `'/'`, then it will become what OP asked.

Comment: @sawa That's what I have written `p a.split("/",2).map(&:strip)` to remove the space, If I have to write `'/ '` then why do I use the second parameter as 2? That's where my answer differ from rest of the answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
"1 Bedroom / 1 1/2 Bath".split("/ ", 2)
# => ["1 Bedroom ", "1 1/2 Bath"]

"1 Bedroom / 1/2 Bath".split("/ ", 2)
# => ["1 Bedroom ", "1/2 Bath"]
```